# Powershell Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true not working

Tags: powershell, security, cmd, windows-defender

To disable the Windows Defender, I am using the PowerShell (as an administrator) in Windows 10 to run the following command:
 `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true`

But the real time protection is not getting disabled.

Can anyone have any idea about how to disable the real time protection programmatically?

Comment: Are you running the command as administrator ? This work fine on my end (Windows 10). I do get a popup suggesting I turn it back on and looking a Virus & threat protection, I see it toggling on and off as I run the commands with `$true / $false` setting.

Comment: Yes, I am running the command as administrator

Answer (score 6):

Tamper Protection (when enabled) prevents "Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true" from doing anything.

Comment: Do you know about any way around it?

Comment: @MaorDahan You can disable it from the Virus and Threats panel in Windows Security, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/28561/how-to-enable-disable-tamper-protection-in-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Although on my Windows 10 machine, the `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` works as expected, you could try manipulating it in the registry directly:

```
# Windows Defender DisableRealtimeMonitoring
$regpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender"
if (!(Test-Path $regpath -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $regpath -ItemType Container -Force
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name "DisableRealtimeMonitoring" -Value 1 -Type DWord -Force
# restart the service
Restart-Service  -Name WinDefend -Confirm:$false -Force
```

To turn it back on, either remove the "DisableRealtimeMonitoring" entry or set its value to DWORD `0`

Comment: I got an error


`Restart-Service : Service 'Windows Defender Antivirus Service (WinDefend)' cannot be stopped due to the following
error: Cannot open WinDefend service on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restart-Service  -Name WinDefend -Confirm:$false -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service
   ], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand`

Comment: Try disablingTamper Protection first

Answer (score -2):

i used key press

ctrl + esc
type string "virus protect"
enter
tab x 4
enter
blahblah = the rest of the key presses to turn off defender and firewall and everything erlse like uninstall avast and avg lol