# Powershell `Set-MpPreference` not recognized

Tags: powershell

On running `Set-MpPreference -DisableScriptScanning 1`, I'm getting:

```
The term 'Set-MpPreference' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MpPreference -DisableScriptScanning 1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-MpPreference:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've gone through the following threads, but nothing seems to work:

- [Add-MpPreference is not recognized as a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881583/add-mppreference-is-not-recognized-as-a-name)
- [Powershell Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035145/powershell-set-mppreference-disablerealtimemonitoring-true-not-working)

I'm using Powershell v5.1 on Windows 7.
What could the reason be?

Comment: If you run the 32bit version of Powershell, try to use the 64bit version instead.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
Import-Module Defender
```

I am not sure if the module exists on Windows 7 yet tough...

Answer (score 1):

Use 64bit Powershell:

```
C:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```